# How to configure AWS Certificate in EC2 instance Running Windows Server 2012R12

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2

I'm having issues referencing AWS issued Certificate in IIS of an EC2 instance with Windows operating system. I have been issued a certificate by AWS, in my EC2 instance, I created an Application Load Balancer and configured it. After setting up everything in AWS console, In IIS I right-clicked on the website and choose edit bindings... to add a new binding type, I choose https but couldn't find the SSL certificate that I created from AWS in the drop-down. Please how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: "I have been issued a certificate by AWS", what kind of certificate? In which format? Certificates won't magically appear on Windows/IIS.

Comment: I was issued an HTTP/HTTPS type of certificate by AWS, no type of file was sent to me, therefore the certificate was not in any format.

Comment: Well, what you said indicates that you don't even know what you were doing, public certificate or private, https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/getting-started/?nc=sn&loc=7 Therefore, AWS support guys should be a better option to help you out, as they can verify your account to see what exactly you did.

Comment: @Lex Li thanks for your timely response, I will ask AWS guys for support and clarity about AWS SSL/TLS Certificate.